# Return to int main() instead of to previous function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, function, calculator

I'm a newbie to programming and this is the first program I'm designing. It's a calculator and in one section I ask the user to input whether he/she wants to input another sum, and if they say yes, repeat the input x, input operator, input y and add them all up process. The only problem I'm having is that if you repeat the process more than once and then finish... the function returns to itself(the previous caller) and not to main like I want it do. So far I've tried `#pragma once`, `#define` and using an extra function but the solution still goes pants down.

I find this hard to explain so here's the whole program so you can see what. I'm talking about:

```
    // Simple Calculator v3.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "tots.h"

double userInput()

{
    using namespace std;
    //Prompt the user to enter a digit
    cout << "  Please enter a digit:  " << endl;
    cout << "  ";

    //Declare a variable and assign the user's input to that variable
    double input;
    cin >> input;

    //Return the digit the user entered
    return input;
}

int userOperatorInput()

{
    using namespace std;
    //Prompt the user to enter an operator
    cout << "  Please enter the desired mathematical operation:  "
         << "+ = 1; - = 2, * = 3, / = 4  " << endl;
    cout << "  ";

    //Declare a variable and assign the user's input to that variable
    int op;
    cin >> op;

    //Return the operator the user entered;
    return op;
}

int userFinished()

{
    using namespace std;
    /*Ask the user whether he/she has entered the function he/she desires or if they have not
    yet finished*/
    cout << "  Have you finished the function?  "
         << "yes = 1; no = 0" << endl;
    cout << "  ";

    //Declare a variable and assign the user's input to that variable
    int userfinished;
    cin >> userfinished;

    //Return the user's input
    return userfinished;
}

double calculateSolution(double input1, int op, double input2)

{
    //Determine which operator the user entered and calculate the solution accordingly
    if (op == 1)
        return input1 + input2;
    else if (op == 2)
        return input1 - input2;
    else if (op == 3)
        return input1 * input2;
    else if (op == 4)
        return input1 / input2;

    else return -1;
}

double moreCalculus(double solution)

{
    double xtrainput1 = solution;
    int xtraop = userOperatorInput();
    double xtrainput2 = userInput();

    double xtrasolution = calculateSolution(xtrainput1, xtraop, xtrainput2);

    bool xtrafinished = userFinished();

    if (xtrafinished == 0)
        moreCalculus(xtrasolution);
    else
    {
       #ifndef RETURN
       #define RETURN

        return xtrasolution;

       #endif
    }
}

void displaySolution(double input1, int op, double input2, double solution)

{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "  " << input1 << "  " << op << "  " << input2 << "  =  " << solution << endl;
}

void displayXtraSolution(double xtrasolution)

{
    using namespace std;
    cout << setprecision(20);
    cout << "  Solution:  " << xtrasolution;
}

void end()

{
    using namespace std;

    int x;
    cin >> x;
}

int main()

{
    //Input from the user
    double input1 = userInput();

    //Operation user requires
    int op        = userOperatorInput();

    //Second input from user
    double input2 = userInput();

    /*Declare and assign a boolean that informs whether the user has finished
      the operation or not*/
    bool finished = userFinished();

    //Calculate the solution
    double solution = calculateSolution(input1, op, input2);

    //If the user has finished, display the solution
    /*If the user hasn't finished, assign the required inputs from the user and calculate the
      solution*/
    if (finished == 1)
    {
        displaySolution(input1, op, input2, solution);
    }

    else
    {
        double xtrasolution = moreCalculus(solution);

        displayXtraSolution(xtrasolution);
    }

    /*Finally, display some information on screen and ask whether the user requires to calculate
      any more operations or if he/she wants to terminate the application*/
```

Note that I made a header file that contains `"stdafx.h"` and `<iostream>`.

Comment: If you think `#pragma once` would somehow help, then you *really* need to go back to whatever resource you have for learning C++. That being said, what you want is a loop.

Comment: jumping back and forth like that is what made [BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC) such a hated language, as it creates [*spaghetti code*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code) which is hard to impossible to follow, understand and maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be looking at [loops](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_loop_types.htm), if your code needs to stop you just break out of it.

Answer (score 0):

use do..while loop

```
    int main(){
    do{
    //your code section
    cout<<"Do you want to continue(Y/N):";
    cin>>ch;
    }while(ch=='Y'||ch=='y');
    }
```